# Disable on-click event for single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-plugins

Can anyone let me know how to disable on click event for particular column.

Scenario : We displayed user details in a table , once click has been made on the table row, popup dialog window will appears with more details(Calling ajax request to retrieve details from database) . But our constraint is to disable on click event for single column associated with the table.

Eg :

```
<table border = '1'>
<tr>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Id </th>
<th> Phone Number</th>
</tr>
<tr onclick = "testing()">
<td> Krupa </td>
<td> 123 </td>
<td id = "disableClick"> <a href = "http://www.google.com" target= '_blank'>Click me </a> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If click has been made on text(1st and 2nd column) , it will invoke on click event . But if user clicks on hyper link (3rd column) , i want to redirecting it to Google but not on-click event(testing()).

Can anyone help me to achieve this .

Comment: can you share your table markup?

Comment: Some code, any code, would go a long way here

Comment: @adeneo and it gets two upvotes. great.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```js
$(function() {
  $('table td').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).index() == 2) {
      return false; // disable 3rd column
    }
  });
  $('table tr').on('click', function() {
    alert('You click the row');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks jcubic , but the problem is my 3rd column contains hyperlink . Once click has been made to the link , i want it to redirecting to given address but not on click event .                                                                    Can you please help me to achieve this

Comment: @Krupa links in 4rd column should work, you only disable click for td.

Comment: @Krupa The other solution is add `e.stopPropagaion()` to click on a tag.

Answer (score 1):

do this through CSS

```
table td:nth-child(2) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raheel . But the problem is my 3rd contains hyperlink . Once click has been made to the link , i want it to redirecting to given address but not on click event .                                                                                                 Can you please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: @Krupa do not call click event on tr call it on td through jquery

$('table td:not(#disableClick)').click(function(){
 alert('test');
});

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the click event to run once, you theoretically could use jquery's `.one()` feature instead of `.on()`. This will automatically unbind the event after running once. Of course this would mean you would have to bind the event again afterwards (if you need it)

http://api.jquery.com/one/

For example

```
$('.selector').one('click', function(){
    // your callback functionality
});
```

Another thing you could do would be to somehow check if the `popup` is active, and prevent the click handler from running if so

For example

```
$('.selector').on('click', function(){
    if (check_if_popup_is_active) {
        return;
    }
    // otherwise continue with
    // your callback functionality
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.unbind()` function from within your callback.

Consider following table for instance

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class='foo'>bar</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

We can stop `onclick` events on `th.foo` as following

```
$('th').on('click', '.foo', function() {
  var that = this;

  // your AJAX call goes here

  success: function() {
    $(that).unbind('click');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding your click events to the column, then removing the event once it has been clicked using [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). This will remove the event of the column that was clicked, but any others should still work.

```
$( '.column' ).on( 'click', function()
{
    // do ajax stuff... 

    // remove event 
    $( this ).unbind(); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via CSS

```
you_css_selector {pointer-events:none;}
```