# Disabling the link only for specific <td> from a linked row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The link has provided for whole row. so that when clicks on the check box & star, it takes me to the linked page but it should not take me to linked page, I searched & I didn't get result. Since I'm new to this, I couldn't step forward. Is there any way to prevent the link for specific td in row? If yes, could you explain me?

```js
$(".star-ttip").tooltip({
 title: 'Star'
});
$(".inquiries #check-all").click(function() {
 if ($("#check-all").is(':checked')) {
  $(".inquiries input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
   $(this).prop("checked", true);
   $(this).closest('tr').addClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
   $(this).parents().find('.mini').addClass("clr-blk");
  });
 } else {
  $(".inquiries input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
   $(this).prop("checked", false);
   $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
   $(this).parents().find('.mini').removeClass("clr-blk");
  });
 }
});
$(".inquiries>tbody>tr>td>input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
 if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass(".table-hover");
  $(this).parents().find('.mini').addClass("clr-blk");
 } else {
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
  $(this).parents().find('.mini').removeClass("clr-blk");
 }
});
```

```css
.table-inbox {
 border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table-inbox tr td {
 padding: 11px !important;
}
.table-inbox tr td:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.table-inbox tr td .fa-star.inbox-started, .table-inbox tr td .fa-star:hover {
 color: #ffcc29;
}
.table-inbox tr td .fa-star {
 color: #d5d5d5;
}
.mail-option {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-bottom: none;
}
.mail-option .chk-all, .mail-option .btn-group a.btn {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fcfcfc;
 border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
 border-radius: 0px !important;
 color: #afafaf;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 12px 10px;
}
.mail-option .chk-all input[type="checkbox"] {
 margin-top: 0;
}
.mail-option .btn-group a.all {
 border: medium none;
 padding: 0;
}
.heading-inbox h4 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 color: #444;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.mail-option>div:first-child {
 padding: 14px 0px 0px 10px;
}
thead {
 color: #ccc;
}
.inquiries {
 border-collapse: initial !important;
}
.inquiries>thead>tr>th {
 border-bottom: none;
 padding: 4px 8px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.inquiries tbody tr td:last-child {
 width: 11%;
}
.inquiries tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
 width: 25%;
 /*padding-left: 0px !important;*/
}
.inquiries tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
 padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.sender-img {
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 6px;
 /*vertical-align: top;*/
}
.inquire-progress {
 margin: 5px 5px 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 190px;
}
.inquiries>thead>tr>th>input {
 margin-left: 3px;
}
.clr-blk {
 color: #000 !important;
}
.inquire-noti {
 border-radius: 50%;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.mail-option>div>a {}
.tabbable-panel {}
.tabbable-line {
 padding-bottom: 18px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li {
 margin-right: 2px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:last-child:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: -9px;
 bottom: -11px;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
 border-right: 9px solid transparent;
 border-left: 9px solid transparent;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.pointer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: 44px;
 bottom: 19px;
 margin: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #dddddd;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a {
 border: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 color: #737373;
 font-size: 17px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav>li>a:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-inbox table-hover inquiries table-responsive">

               <thead> 
                 <tr>
                  <th colspan="">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
                    </th>
                    <th style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
                  <!-- <th><span class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle select-all-drpdwn-icon" data-toggle="dropdown" id="select-all">
                  <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu select-all-drpdwn" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Read</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Unread</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Starred</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Unstarred</a></li>
              </ul>
          </span></th> -->
                  <th>SENDER</th>
                  <th>SUBJECT</th>
                  <th>COUNTRY</th>
                  <th>UPDATED</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="unread" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan</td>
                    <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
                    <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Ilaya raja </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Anirudh</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir.. </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                     China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan</td>
                    <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
                    <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Ilaya raja </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Anirudh</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir.. </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                      China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                      China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan</td>
                    <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
                    <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Ilaya raja </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Anirudh</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir.. </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                      China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: if you remove the onclick event from the tr and put it in all of the td elements you wish to react to the onclick event it should work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to work.

I added the class clickAction to the rows where you want to have the event.

```
$("tr.clickAction> td:not(:nth-child(1), :nthchild(2))").on("click",function()
{
   document.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

This will apply onclick on every TD inside the TR with clickAction class except for the first 2 TD.

```js
$("tr.clickAction> td:not(:nth-child(1), :nth-child(2))").on("click",function(){
   document.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});

$(".star-ttip").tooltip({
 title: 'Star'
});
$(".inquiries #check-all").click(function() {
 if ($("#check-all").is(':checked')) {
  $(".inquiries input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
   $(this).prop("checked", true);
   $(this).closest('tr').addClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
   $(this).parents().find('.mini').addClass("clr-blk");
  });
 } else {
  $(".inquiries input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
   $(this).prop("checked", false);
   $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
   $(this).parents().find('.mini').removeClass("clr-blk");
  });
 }
});
$(".inquiries>tbody>tr>td>input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
 if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass(".table-hover");
  $(this).parents().find('.mini').addClass("clr-blk");
 } else {
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
  $(this).parents().find('.mini').removeClass("clr-blk");
 }
});
```

```css
.table-inbox {
 border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table-inbox tr td {
 padding: 11px !important;
}
.table-inbox tr td:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.table-inbox tr td .fa-star.inbox-started, .table-inbox tr td .fa-star:hover {
 color: #ffcc29;
}
.table-inbox tr td .fa-star {
 color: #d5d5d5;
}
.mail-option {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-bottom: none;
}
.mail-option .chk-all, .mail-option .btn-group a.btn {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fcfcfc;
 border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
 border-radius: 0px !important;
 color: #afafaf;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 12px 10px;
}
.mail-option .chk-all input[type="checkbox"] {
 margin-top: 0;
}
.mail-option .btn-group a.all {
 border: medium none;
 padding: 0;
}
.heading-inbox h4 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 color: #444;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.mail-option>div:first-child {
 padding: 14px 0px 0px 10px;
}
thead {
 color: #ccc;
}
.inquiries {
 border-collapse: initial !important;
}
.inquiries>thead>tr>th {
 border-bottom: none;
 padding: 4px 8px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.inquiries tbody tr td:last-child {
 width: 11%;
}
.inquiries tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
 width: 25%;
 /*padding-left: 0px !important;*/
}
.inquiries tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
 padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.sender-img {
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 6px;
 /*vertical-align: top;*/
}
.inquire-progress {
 margin: 5px 5px 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 190px;
}
.inquiries>thead>tr>th>input {
 margin-left: 3px;
}
.clr-blk {
 color: #000 !important;
}
.inquire-noti {
 border-radius: 50%;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.mail-option>div>a {}
.tabbable-panel {}
.tabbable-line {
 padding-bottom: 18px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 0px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li {
 margin-right: 2px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:last-child:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: -9px;
 bottom: -11px;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
 border-right: 9px solid transparent;
 border-left: 9px solid transparent;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.pointer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: 44px;
 bottom: 19px;
 margin: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #dddddd;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a {
 border: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 color: #737373;
 font-size: 17px;
}
.tabbable-line>.nav>li>a:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-inbox table-hover inquiries table-responsive">

               <thead> 
                 <tr>
                  <th colspan="">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
                    </th>
                    <th style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
                  <!-- <th><span class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle select-all-drpdwn-icon" data-toggle="dropdown" id="select-all">
                  <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu select-all-drpdwn" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Read</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Unread</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Starred</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Unstarred</a></li>
              </ul>
          </span></th> -->
                  <th>SENDER</th>
                  <th>SUBJECT</th>
                  <th>COUNTRY</th>
                  <th>UPDATED</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="unread clickAction">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 "></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan</td>
                    <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
                    <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread clickAction">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 "></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Ilaya raja </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="clickAction">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells ">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 "></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Anirudh</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir.. </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="clickAction">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells ">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 "></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                     China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="clickAction">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells ">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started "></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan</td>
                    <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
                    <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Ilaya raja </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Anirudh</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir.. </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                      China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                      China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan</td>
                    <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
                    <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
                    <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="unread">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Ilaya raja </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Anirudh</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir.. </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Aadhi</td>
                    <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
                      China
                    </td>
                    <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
                    <td class="view-message dont-show"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25" class="sender-img">Pugal </td>
                    <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :) </td>
                    <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
                    <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code 
[How to prevent row click function on specific column in datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720057/how-to-prevent-row-click-function-on-specific-column-in-datatable) or you can check this link
[Disable on-click event for single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750578/disable-on-click-event-for-single-column)
you can prevent a specific column to perform onclick function but you have to provide that column index to your javascript function or through css class
for your code

```
table td:nth-child(2) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
table td:nth-child(1) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

add it into your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an inline onClick event handler with a redirection action you can select just those rows and stop the propagation to the row when clicking on an inner cell.

The code to be added:

```
$('table.table tbody tr[onClick] td').on('click', function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The selector '.table tbody tr[onClick] td' means: select a table having the class table and so get the tbody element and for each contained row select only the ones with the attribute onClick. For each of such row get only the related td elements.

[e.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/): prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. (i.e.: stop to propagate the event to the corresponding row, so the inline onClick will not be executed)

```js
//
//  ADD THIS LINE
//
$('table.table tbody tr[onClick] td').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Stopped propagation for: ' + this.tagName);
});


$(".star-ttip").tooltip({
    title: 'Star'
});
$(".inquiries #check-all").click(function () {
    if ($("#check-all").is(':checked')) {
        $(".inquiries input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
            $(this).parents().find('.mini').addClass("clr-blk");
        });
    } else {
        $(".inquiries input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
            $(this).parents().find('.mini').removeClass("clr-blk");
        });
    }
});
$(".inquiries>tbody>tr>td>input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass(".table-hover");
        $(this).parents().find('.mini').addClass("clr-blk");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("inq-checked-clr clr-blk");
        $(this).parents().find('.mini').removeClass("clr-blk");
    }
});
```

```css
.table-inbox {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table-inbox tr td {
    padding: 11px !important;
}

.table-inbox tr td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table-inbox tr td .fa-star.inbox-started, .table-inbox tr td .fa-star:hover {
    color: #ffcc29;
}

.table-inbox tr td .fa-star {
    color: #d5d5d5;
}

.mail-option {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.mail-option .chk-all, .mail-option .btn-group a.btn {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fcfcfc;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    color: #afafaf;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 10px;
}

.mail-option .chk-all input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.mail-option .btn-group a.all {
    border: medium none;
    padding: 0;
}

.heading-inbox h4 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.mail-option > div:first-child {
    padding: 14px 0px 0px 10px;
}

thead {
    color: #ccc;
}

.inquiries {
    border-collapse: initial !important;
}

.inquiries > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.inquiries tbody tr td:last-child {
    width: 11%;
}

.inquiries tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
    /*padding-left: 0px !important;*/
}

.inquiries tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.sender-img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 6px;
    /*vertical-align: top;*/
}

.inquire-progress {
    margin: 5px 5px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 190px;
}

.inquiries > thead > tr > th > input {
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.clr-blk {
    color: #000 !important;
}

.inquire-noti {
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.mail-option > div > a {
}

.tabbable-panel {
}

.tabbable-line {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li {
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li:last-child:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    bottom: -11px;
    border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li.pointer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 44px;
    bottom: 19px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li > a {
    border: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.tabbable-line > .nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-inbox table-hover inquiries table-responsive">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
        </th>
        <th style="visibility: hidden;"></th>
        <!-- <th><span class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle select-all-drpdwn-icon" data-toggle="dropdown" id="select-all">
  <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu select-all-drpdwn" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Read</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Unread</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Starred</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Unstarred</a></li>
</ul>
</span></th> -->
        <th>SENDER</th>
        <th>SUBJECT</th>
        <th>COUNTRY</th>
        <th>UPDATED</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="unread" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan
        </td>
        <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
        <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Ilaya raja
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
        <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Anirudh
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir..</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
        <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Aadhi
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
            China
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan
        </td>
        <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
        <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Ilaya raja
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
        <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Anirudh
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir..</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
        <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Aadhi
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
            China
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Aadhi
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
            China
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Santhosh naarayanan
        </td>
        <td class="view-message ">Hello sir...</td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show">India</td>
        <td class="view-message">9:27 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Ilaya raja
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Hi...santhosh, Wasup?</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">UK</td>
        <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Anirudh
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Thaara thappatai Awsome sir..</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">Canada</td>
        <td class="view-message">Mar 15, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Aadhi
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Yes, it was nice</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">
            China
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">Apr 01, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=""><i class="fa fa-star star-ttip fnt-size-18 inbox-started"></i></td>
        <td class="view-message dont-show"><img
                src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages/left-column/prompt-customer-service.jpg" width="25" height="25"
                class="sender-img">Pugal
        </td>
        <td class="view-message">I'm about sing guys... :)</td>
        <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells">US</td>
        <td class="view-message">May 23, 16</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```